# Voiced labiodental fricative in Puerto Rican Spanish?

Tags: phonology, spanish

I was listening to "[Despacito](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJQP7kiw5Fk)", and it seems that both singers use /v/ (Fonsi at 0:42 with his mouth visible, DY at 1:00) as an allophone of native /β/ (still used, e.g Fonsi, 1:52).

Most Spanish speakers I know only pronounce /β/ labiodentally when smiling through rapid speech (on which occasion they'd also pronounce /p/ and /m/ labiodentally).

Is this standard in Puerto Rican Spanish?

Answer (score 4):

Found in the abstract of a presentation ([Exford 2016](https://www.sccur.org/sccur/fall_2016_conference/oral_talks/237/)):

> Native Spanish speaking college students in San Juan, Puerto Rico that are bilingual in English to some degree are interviewed to perform audio-recorded speaking tasks. Results show that labiodentals are undoubtedly produced for Spanish phoneme /b/, but are done so exclusively for orthographic *v*. On average, grapheme *v* was pronounced as a labiodental 56% of the time. Grapheme *b* was never pronounced as a labiodental. In addition to orthography, the results speculate that labiodentals are also conditioned by speech style or formality, as labiodental frequency reduced when tasks became more informal.

So [v] for /b/ spelled *v* does seem fairly common in Puerto Rican Spanish. The author suggests it may be an effect of hypercorrection.

Answer (score 0):

My father was born in Puerto Rico, and due to my initial informal education in the language I actually thought it was a hard V sound and spelled it accordingly (saves), and is how my family (and myself) tend to pronounce it to this day. It might be more of a rural thing though, as my father's family comes from a small farm on the coast.